# Logic of parallel package in R

Tags: r

```
> library(parallel)
> foo <- "Hello"
> f <- function(text) {
+   foo <- text
+   parLapply(cl, 1:2, function(i) print(foo))
+ }
> cl <- makeCluster(2, type="FORK")
> foo <- "Goodbye"
> parLapply(cl, 1:2, function(i) print(foo))
[[1]]
[1] "Hello"

[[2]]
[1] "Hello"

> f(foo)
[[1]]
[1] "Goodbye"

[[2]]
[1] "Goodbye"
```

In the above codes, it appears that when I do makeCluster(), the objects in the global environment are copied over to the child processes. Thus, when I later modify the objects in the master process, the change is not copied over. This logic I understand. However, if parLapply() is called within a function, objects defined within the function seem to be copied over after the makeCluster() call. What causes the difference in the two scenarios?